# Issue with h1 element inside div element

Tags: html, css

I have 2 files: 1 is `.html` file and another file is `.css` file
and here are their content:

```css
#left,
#right {
  display: inline-block;
}

#left {
  width: 15%;
  height: 550px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#right {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">
</div>
<div id="right">
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="content">
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

If I add 1 `<h1>` element inside `#left` or `#header, #footer, #content` **then their position move down**.
I don't know why it happens. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is adding default margin and padding to the h1 element (likely on the top) that is affecting the parent element. Go to the browser and click on inspect element. This will show you the default value. You can then specify the values in your code according to your need.